# Javascript Update form field based on data in previous field

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have a quoting form that pulls data from a db using PHP. One of the fields that is pulled from the DB is the partner level (silver, gold, platinum).

The field below partner level shows the discount % that the partner receives based on the level they are (higher level equals higher discount).

Once the form loads and the partner level is pulled in from the DB I would like the field below partner level to show the discount based on which level of partner the user is.

Here is the fieldset of the form I currently have set up:

```
<fieldset>
                            <div class="form-top">
                                <div class="form-top-left">
                                    <h2>Partner Information</h2>
                                    <h3>Tell us who you are</h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-top-right">
                                    <img src="assets/images/icons/partner_info.png" class="form-icon">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-bottom">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="form-partner-name" placeholder="Partner name" class="form-partner-name form-control" id="form-partner-name" 
                                            value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user']['firstName'], " ", $_SESSION['user']['lastName']?>">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="form-partner-level" placeholder="Partner Level" class="form-partner-level form-control" id="form-partner-level" 
                                            value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user']['partnerLvl']?>">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="discount-perc" placeholder="Discount(%)" class="form-control" id="form-discount-perc">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" name="form-margin-perc" placeholder="Margin(%)" class="form-control" id="form-margin-perc">
                                    </div>
                                <br />
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-next">Next</button>
                            </div>
</fieldset>
```

How do update the discount field by reading the value of the partner level field using javascript?

Comment: Two of your fields have `id="form-partner-name"` - you want to fix that.

Comment: Good catch, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The input should be:

```
<input type="text" name="form-partner-level" placeholder="Partner level" class="form-partner-name form-control" id="form-partner-level" 'onblur="updateDiscount()"'
value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user']['partnerLvl']?>">
```

Then the script is

```
<script language="javascript"><!--
function updateDiscount() {
   var level = document.forms["your-form"].form-partner-level.value;
 var discount = document.forms["your-form"].discount-perc.value;

  if (level == "Platinum") {
    discount = 20;
  } else {
    discount = something-else;
  }
//--></script>
```

*** Update: OP asks for calculation on page load.  In this case:

```
<?php 
      if ($_SESSION['user']['partnerLvl'] == "Platinum") {
        $discount = 20;
      } else {
        $discount = something-else;
      }
... 

    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="discount-perc"  class="form-control" id="form-discount-perc" value="<?php echo $discount; ?>" />
```

Comment: I see what you're getting at here, but I don't think this exact solution would work. onkeyup fires when the user releases a key, but there are no key inputs being performed when the page loads.

The second issue is that the js needs to read the string value and translate that into a discount level (i.e. if partner-level== "Platinum" then set the discount% value to 20%).

Comment: Changed to onblur.  But I'm a bit unclear on why the discount is an input field.  Also the name and level are still using the same id and name which is quite confusing.

Comment: I updated the IDs to so they are different. The discount is an input field because it makes the formatting on the page more consistent. I believe that the onblur() event fires when a user leaves a field. What I need this to appear when the form first loads. Perhaps I should set this value in my database and have it load in at the same time as the partner level field?

Comment: Updated. Please reformat your code so it's easier to read.  You need to move the lines between the first and the last WAY over to the left so I don't have to keep horizontally scrolling.